# Custom info in Jmeter dashboard

Tags: testing, jmeter

Trying to add my own table to Jmeter dashboard report. In Jmeter it's not clear enough. Tried as in https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html#customs_graphs
but the custom part doesn't appear in dashboard. Would appreciate your help and examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the documentation you're referring is not comprehensive enough, the chapter assumes that you can plot the numeric value of a [Sample Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/listeners.html#sample_variables)

So if you put the next line to [*user.properties* file](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-properties-customization) (lives in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation)

```
sample_variables=ts-hit
```

and copy and paste the example configuration from the [documentation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html#customs_graphs):

```
jmeter.reportgenerator.graph.custom_testGraph.classname=org.apache.jmeter.report.processor.graph.impl.CustomGraphConsumer
jmeter.reportgenerator.graph.custom_testGraph.title=Chunk Hit
jmeter.reportgenerator.graph.custom_testGraph.property.set_Y_Axis=Number of Hits
jmeter.reportgenerator.graph.custom_testGraph.set_X_Axis=Over Time
jmeter.reportgenerator.graph.custom_testGraph.property.set_granularity=60000
jmeter.reportgenerator.graph.custom_testGraph.property.set_Sample_Variable_Name=ts-hit
jmeter.reportgenerator.graph.custom_testGraph.property.set_Content_Message=Number of Hits :
```

Create some fake values for the `ts-hit` variable using i.e. [__Random() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__Random):

[image]

As the result you should see something like this:

[image]

With regards to custom tables - as of JMeter 5.5 it's not possible, however if you're comfortable with [FreeMarker](https://freemarker.apache.org/) you can amend the [template](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/tree/rel/v5.5/bin/report-template) and add whatever you want there